# Java Timeout for an inactive user

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx-2

I have a problem with the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

I need a timeout which will redirect to the first page after `'n'-seconds`. If the user enters a character, the timer should start counting again and may not redirect to the first page. 
(So the counter should abort his scheduled Task)

The Problem is, that the Timer starts, but it doesn't cancel the scheduled Task if a key was typed. The `stop()` - Method will be called. But `scheduledThreadPool.shutdownNow();` seems not to work.

**My TimerClass looks like this:**

```
public class MyTimer {

    private final Runnable logicalWorker;

    private final long delay;

    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPool;

    public MyTimer(final Runnable logicalWorker, final long delay) {
        scheduledThreadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        this.logicalWorker = logicalWorker;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void start() {
        scheduledThreadPool.schedule(logicalWorker, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void stop() {
        scheduledThreadPool.shutdownNow();
        scheduledThreadPool.getQueue().clear();
    }

    public void restart() {
        start();
    }

    public boolean isScheduled() {
        return !scheduledThreadPool.isTerminated() && !scheduledThreadPool.isShutdown();
    }
}
```

**The method in a superclass which calls the timerClass is this one:**

```
protected void startTimeout() {
    if (currentInstance.getAutoTimeout() != null && currentInstance.getAutoTimeout().isScheduled()) {
        currentInstance.getAutoTimeout().restart();
        return;
    }
    currentInstance.setAutoTimeout(new MyTimer(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!PageContent.PAGE_ID.equals(currentInstance.getPageId()) && !forceOpen) {
                        cancelCurrentProcesses();
                        switchPageByPageId(PageContent.PAGE_ID);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, currentInstance.getPageDelay()));
    if (currentInstance.getPageDelay() > 0) {
        currentInstance.getAutoTimeout().start();
    }
}
```

**The KeyListener and the MouseClickListener will be set on the scene at the beginning by this method:**

```
protected void placePage() throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
        InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    startTimeout();
    currentInstance.getRoot().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            startTimeout();
        }
    });
    currentInstance.getRoot().setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent arg0) {
            startTimeout();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` for such a simple task seems like an overkill to me. Especially that it is created for each Timer object.

Comment: @Dariusz Doesn't just seem to you, it is rather wasteful. It implies that resources aren't an issue, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

The `shutdownNow()` makes no guarantees to cancel execution.

As for a solution, I recommend you use `ScheduledFuture` or `Future` objects rather than `Runnable`.

[EDIT] A scheduled future, on which you can call a `.cancel()` function instead of `.shutdownNow()` is returned by the `.schedule()` call, which you call, but don't seem to use (or indeed save) the handle to the `Future` anywhere. And yes, you do still need a `Runnable` but only insofar as it will give you the `Future` handle.

Try something like this:

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> future;
public void start() {
    future = scheduledThreadPool.schedule(logicalWorker, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
public void stop() {
    if(future != null) future.cancel();
}
```

[/EDIT]

More details here -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html

Comment: But it does not make sense to have a runnable in a callable in a Future-Object or not?

Comment: It's not a `Runnable` in a `Callable`, it's one of the two; for your example I think you can use either in `ScheduledExecutorService.schedule()` and the return value of that function will be a `ScheduledFuture` on which you can call `cancel()`. There's a good example of that workflow in the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: But it is not possible to cancel this thread before running... Anyway, it does not work for me

Comment: You don't need to explicitly kill the thread, the SF can handle that for you. Check the example in the last edit, or read through a couple of tutorials, google has plenty.